# Android App runs only over Emulator

Tags: android, android-location

I have the following code which sends my phone location to a server through `volley` library, it runs only over emulators but not over any phone.

I can't investigate the error anymore i tried to change my `minSdk` but this leads to nothing.

MinSdk : 17

Target : Android Nougat Api 25 (7.1.1)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button start, stop;
private TextView t;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener listener;
private String url = "https://vamos.comeze.com/api/tracking";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            t.setText("\n " + location.getLongitude() + " " + location.getLatitude());

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("Hellllllllo", "Error Response");
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("longitude", location.getLongitude() + "");
                    params.put("latitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
                    Log.e("Longitude", location.getLongitude() + "");
                    Log.e("Latitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
                    return params;
                }
            };
            MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addTorequestque(stringRequest);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("Start", "Yes on Start");
            configure_button();
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("Stop", "Yes on Stop");
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
            configure_button();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void configure_button() {
    // first check for permissions
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                    , 10);
        }
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 1, listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is the error you get, please add the stack trace? Can you also add your manifest?

Comment: I don't get any errors in the Android Monitor , but I just don't get my location

Comment: Open Google Maps, let it fix a location where you are, and after that open your app and see if you start getting location. And let me know.